# Linear Regression – When is Bad Data “Too Much”?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, outliers

I am doing a multiple linear regression analysis.  One variable, which I think may be quite predictive, has known bad data.  I am currently sampling and using analysts to independently verify the sample data to determine the extent of the data errors.

The data is categorical but mapped to a numeric value.

The particular difficulty in this problem is that in order to have meaning in predicting my dependent variable, the categorical data is subtotaled by observation.

Let me illustrate this with an example:

Assume that I am regressing manufacturing cost on a number of variables.  One such variable is the labor, which is dependent on widget color.  This is my made up example data:

```
Obs.  Widget - 1 Color  Widget 2 - Color  Widget 3 - Color  Widget 4 - Color
1            Red              Yellow            Red              Orange
2           Green              Green           Black              Blue
3           Brown               Red            Purple             Black
```

I have the following map from color to estimated labor costs by color.  (A further important complication in this problem is that the numeric values mapped to are not exactly known, but estimated by Subject Matter Experts).

```
Color   Estimated Labor
Black        10 
Blue         15 
Brown        60 
Green         5 
Orange       35 
Purple      100 
Red          20 
Yellow       95
```

This allows me to compute a net widget labor variable (note – not all observations have the same number of widgets):

```
Obs.  Widget-1    Widget-2   Widget-3   Widget-4   Widget-5    Net Widget
       Labor       Labor      Labor      Labor      Labor        Labor
1        20          95         20         35                     170
2         5           5         10                                 20
3        60          20        100         10         95          285
```

Finally, the rolled up net widget labor is put into the regression equation:

```
Obs.   Net Widget Labor   Factor A   Factor B   Factor C   Net Cost
1            170             15        225        100        1758
2             35             10        185         55        1245
3            285             20        262         95        2025
```

My problem is that I know a certain percentage of my widgets are labeled with the incorrect color.  I don’t know which ones are mislabeled.  There may be certain observations with all widgets classified correctly and there may be others with one or more widgets incorrectly labeled.  Furthermore, because the categorical data types to a map and the difference between any two levels in the map are not the same, I don’t know if the impact of the misclassification is small (green as opposed to black) or large (purple as opposed to green).

Since it’s the net widget labor that is predictive to net cost and the number of widgets by observation can vary considerably (much more than in my toy example) and the SME map to numerical value is not exact, I am not confident of a technique to detect the mislabeled colors.  I am thus concerned that either the variable will be found to be predictive but the coefficient will be inaccurate or the variable will be excluded from the final set of predictive variables.

I thus had two questions:

1. My assumption is that there is not a good way to identify the bad data here.  If I am mistaken, I would appreciate thoughts on how to do that.
2. I am able to get a sense on the extent of the misclassification via random sampling and analyst verification of correct “color”.  What percentage of contamination of the data would be acceptable to allow me to a) be confident that if the variable is included/excluded in the final choice of variables, that is a correct decision and b) that the coefficient, while not perfect, is reasonable?  Part of the complication again is that I don’t know how severely the misclassification impacts corresponding numeric value.

Thank you,